# Codeigniter - brackets with activerecord?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

How to have round brackets symbol in Codeigniter's active record SQL queries?
e.g. how to accomplish

```
SELECT * FROM `shops` WHERE (`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11') AND `shopid` <> '18'
```

Comment: At CI3.0 you can do this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 11):

```
$where="(`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11')";
```

$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);

and for the AND condition use

```
$this->db->where('shopid <>', '18')
```

ie

```
$where="(`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11')";
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->where('shopid <>', '18')
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you could do something like:

```
$where = "(`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11')";

$this->db->where($where)  // or statement here
         ->where('shopid <>', '18') // chaining with AND
         ->get('shops');
```

Not entirely sure about the syntax, I'm writing this off the top of my head. I'll take a look at it when I get home if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like:

```
$this->db->select('field')->from('shops')->where("(`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11'")->where("`shopid` <> '18'");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

> You can write your own clauses
>   manually:
>
> $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss'
>   OR status='active'";
>
> $this->db->where($where);

Source: http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#where

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select()
         ->from('shops')
         ->where("'(`shopid` = '10' OR `shopid` = '11')")
         ->where('shopid !=', 18);

$this->db->get()->result();
```