# codeigniter multiple OR query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use following query in Codeigniter:

```
SELECT `users` . * , `users_profile` . * FROM (`users`) LEFT JOIN `users_profile`
ON `users`.`id` = `users_profile`.`users_id`
WHERE (`loginid` = '$username' OR `email` = '$username' )
AND `password` = '$password' AND `users`.`status` = 'A' LIMIT 1
```

It is working fine, but when I write this query in Codeigniter format:

```
$this->db->where('loginid',"$username");
$this->db->or_where('email', "$username");    
$this->db->where('password',MD5($password));
$this->db->where('users.status','A');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

It will return always true what is right syntax?

Comment: you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175789/codeigniter-brackets-with-activerecord

Comment: $this->db->where("(loginid = '$username' OR email = '$username') 
                   AND password = 'MD5($password) AND status = 'A' AND id = 'users_id')'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the custom string method of where() as this is not possible directly with only ActiveRecord. See [this link from the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) and scroll to the 4th option under the where() function.

Example:

```
    Custom string:

    You can write your own clauses manually:
    $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

    $this->db->where($where);

$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 3):

May be your query should be like this in codeIgniter.......for reference you can see this link 
[Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('users_profile', 'users_profile.id = users.id', 'left');
$this->db->where("(loginid = '$username' OR email = '$username') AND password = 'MD5($password) AND status = 'A')'");
```