# Codeigniter active record where is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, codeigniter

I am running CodeIgniter, using active records. Below is my table structure:

```
id (int)   user (int)   is_complete (tinyint)
------------------------------------------------
1          24           1
2          24           1
3          24           NULL
4          24           0
5          24           0
```

## Case 1

```php
$this->db->where('user', 24);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = 24
```

**Works** and returns:

```
id   user   is_complete
--------------------------
1    24     1
2    24     1
3    24     NULL
4    24     0
5    24     0
```

## Case 2

```php
$this->db->where('user', 24);
$this->db->where('is_complete', 1);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = 24 AND `is_complete` = 1
```

**Works** and returns:

```
id   user   is_complete
--------------------------
1    24     1
2    24     1
```

## Case 3

```php
$this->db->where('user', 24);
$this->db->where('is_complete !=', 1);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = 24 AND `is_complete` != 1
```

**Does not work** and is returning:

```
id   user   is_complete
--------------------------
4    24     0
5    24     0
```

## Case 4

```php
$this->db->where('user', 24);
$this->db->where('is_complete <>', 1);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = 24 AND `is_complete` <> 1
```

**Does not work** and is returning:

```
id   user   is_complete
--------------------------
4    24     0
5    24     0
```

## Result Needed

It **should** return:

```
id   user   is_complete
--------------------------
3    24     NULL
4    24     0
5    24     0
```

Am I doing something wrong using the `where()` method, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: and if you're comparing it to `0` or `NULL` - you get the desired output?

Comment: `0` does not work, `NULL` does work

Comment: **Correction**: `0` does work, `NULL` does work

Comment: Can you please debug the query? I mean, output the sql query that those commands create?

Comment: Debug the query with `echo $this->db->last_query();` copy and paste the query in phpMyAdmin and check if it works.

Comment: Ok I updated with queries and newest results. It's NOT grabbing `NULL` values.

Comment: in active record you need to do this to accept `null` `$where_array = ('id IS NULL' => NULL);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue at the database level, though it is not a bug - this is how SQL works with null values. This query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    `user` = 24 AND `is_complete` != 1
```

will return records where `is_complete` is not equal to 1, but not null. If you wish to include null records as well, you will need to do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    `user` = 24 AND
    (`is_complete` != 1 OR `is_complete` IS NULL)
```

By comparing a column with a non-null value, you've automatically excluded nulls, which need to be treated with a different syntax.

You'll need to add in an additional, bracketed clause for the query; [see here for how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175853/472495).

Comment: So if `is_complete` also has values of '2' and '3' I would use the same syntax that you provided? Because `!= 1` will take care of ALL values (0,2,3) except `NULL` and the `IS NULL` handles any `NULL` values?

Comment: Yep, that's correct `:)`. The "not equals" will work on any real values, except null.

Comment: Awesome! Just tried it and working exactly how I want, I used the bracketed `where()` clause and that worked too. Thanks

Comment: Great. I would guess that where you inject your own values into a `where()` string, you need to manually untaint them. For integers, you can just cast to `(int)`, though hopefully there is also a parameterisation system in CI ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 3 is working**. `NULL` is different in SQL to a number, and needs a different comparator. The way I think of it is that NULL is the absence of anything, whereas 0 is the number 0; it is a subtle difference.
So `!= 1` gives all numbers except 1, whereas to find null you must use the `is` / `is not null` comparator.

The query to find you *required* result is:

```
$this->db->where("((is_complete = 0) OR (is_complete is null))",NULL,FALSE);
```

Searching for `!= 1` isn't the same as searching for `= 0`. (If it is possible `is_complete` has a value that is say '3'. You may get fewer problems in your code if you search for what you want, rather instead of what shouldn't be there).

The `where` statement expects a second parameter if the third (FALSE) parameter to remove backticks is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use active records for multi database support.

You can use active records like that for your query

**Case 3**

```
$this->db->where('user', 24, FALSE);
$this->db->where('is_complete !=', 1, FALSE);
```

**Case 4**

```
$this->db->where('user', 24, FALSE);
$this->db->where('is_complete <>', 1, FALSE);
```

Third parameter is used to remove the back tick which causes sql query issue.